# Как найти все, что находится между двумя символами в строке Python?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, теги

допустим у меня есть строка:

```
'строка <, которую 123>надо<разделить>'
```

И я хочу получить из нее:

```
', которую 123 разделить'
```

То есть мне нужно все, что находится между <>.
У меня есть код:

```
import re
regex = re.compile("\<(.*)\>")
regex.findall('строка <, которую 123>надо<разделить>')
```

Но выводит у меня не то, что нужно:

```
', которую 123>надо<разделить'
```

Comment: Использовать не жадный `(.*?)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте

```py
import re
text = 'строка <, которую 123>надо<разделить>'
print( ' '.join(re.findall(r'<([^<>]+)>', text)) )
# => , которую 123 разделить
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/OtVUBg) и [регулряного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/urqpHM/1).

Выражение `<([^<>]+)>` находит

- `<` - символ `<`
- `([^<>]+)` - один и более символов, отличных от `<` и `>`, захватываемых в подмаску #1
- `>` - символ `>`.

`re.findall` возвращает список значений в первой подмаске, а `' '.join(...)` объединяет их в одну строку.